# AVD manager fails to create virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio

I am not sure what is going on with my Android studio , I follow the create virtual device wizard but it just freezes for few moments after i click finish and then it exits and nothing happens! 
The SDK is full installed and up to date 
Using Android studio v2.2 installed on ubuntu

I ran it from the terminal hoping to see any helpful error messages but all I got was this:

```
[ 268396]  ERROR - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Android Studio 2.2 Beta  Build #AI-145.3128856 
[ 268396]  ERROR - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - JDK: 1.8.0_76-release 
[ 268396]  ERROR - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
[ 268396]  ERROR - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
[ 268396]  ERROR - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - OS: Linux 
[ 268396]  ERROR - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Last Action: Android.RunAndroidAvdManager
```

Is there a work around for this or should I consider downgrading to v2.1 instead of the beta (which was a recommended update!)

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem was in mksdcard in the SDK , i had a missing library which was fixed by installing gcc-multilib.

Comment: Thank you so much! This totally fixed my problem.

What was interesting is when I tried to run `mksdcard` when reading your comment, basically it went like this:

`bash: ./mksdcard: No such file or directory`

So your suggestion to install the Ubuntu package `gcc-multilib` worked!

Upvoted!